# How to get the block number which is the closest to a given timestamp?

Tags: web3js, timestamp, block-interval

Is there any method(ology) in web3 which allows to get the block number at a given date?

In particular, I have two dates as an input and I want to effectively get all events between those two dates. I know that I can do this by having block numbers:

```
contract.Event({}, { fromBlock: 100000, toBlock: 121212 })
```

But is it possible to do so with `Date`s? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ethfinex just published a function that does exactly that.

It's to "pixel perfect" but it's working really well so far, you give it a timestamp and it will walk the blockchain backwards until it finds a block that is very close.

During my tests it always found the nearest block, you might need to tweak it a little bit more.

https://github.com/ethfinex/efx-trustless-vol/blob/master/src/lib/getBlockByTime.js

here are some results

```
tgt timestamp   -> 1545523200
tgt date        -> 2018-12-23T00:00:00Z

block timestamp -> 1545523212
block date      -> 2018-12-23T00:00:12Z

requests made   -> 3

tgt timestamp   -> 1545609600
tgt date        -> 2018-12-24T00:00:00Z

block timestamp -> 1545609592
block date      -> 2018-12-23T23:59:52Z

requests made   -> 4
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the closest answer to what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 9):

DeFiLlama has a new API that does this. https://defillama.com/docs/api

Just GET

```
https://coins.llama.fi/block/ethereum/1658171864
```

You can also check different chains

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but recently I wrote a plugin for this kind of task. Usually, it makes fewer requests than Ethfinex's script does (usually, not always ).

Take a look: https://github.com/monosux/ethereum-block-by-date

Comment: Great work! It would be even greater if you could avoid using moment.js as a dependency (it's a really heavy module). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, you are right, moment is heavy. I used it since I already had it in my project's dependencies. I think I can rewrite code to use moment as optional dependence or do not use moment at all.
It will be cool if you create an issue in the repo: https://github.com/monosux/ethereum-block-by-date/issues So, I will not forget about this idea :)

Answer (score 2):

QuickBlocks has a command line program called 'whenBlock' that takes either a date (or timestamp) and takes the block number that occurred just prior, or a block number and returns the date and timestamp of that block. You can download QuickBlocks here: http://github.com/Great-Hill-Corporation/quickBlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

Your best bet is to take a sample size loop from `latest` to `latest - {x}` block and get the moving average of block time creation. From there you can estimate a block number to get the block time from and loop until you cross the time you need.

Answer (score 1):

Moralis have an API endpoint just for that, so if you already happen to use their API, there's no need to add another dependency.

https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/reference/get-date-to-block?chain=eth

Answer (score 1):

Old question, new answer: [findblock API](https://api.findblock.xyz/#/blocks/get_chain__chainId__block_before__timestamp_) provides you with two endpoints that can do just that

Answer (score 0):

I've created a little function to do a binary search using ether.js.

```
export async function getBlockNumberByTimestamp(
    provider: JsonRpcProvider,
    timestamp: number
): Promise<number> {
    const getBlockTime = async (blockNumber: number) => (await provider.getBlock(blockNumber)).timestamp;
    
    let leftBlockNumber = 0;
    let leftTimestamp = await getBlockTime(leftBlockNumber);
    let rightBlockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
    let rightTimestamp = await getBlockTime(rightBlockNumber);
    
    if (timestamp <= leftTimestamp) {
        return leftBlockNumber;
    }
    
    if (timestamp >= rightTimestamp) {
        return rightBlockNumber;
    }
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition
    while (true) {
        const middleBlockNumber = leftBlockNumber + Math.floor((rightBlockNumber - leftBlockNumber) / 2);
        const middleTimestamp = await getBlockTime(rightBlockNumber);
        if (timestamp === middleTimestamp) {
            return middleBlockNumber;
        } else if (timestamp < middleTimestamp) {
            rightBlockNumber = middleBlockNumber;
            rightTimestamp = middleTimestamp;
        } else {
            leftBlockNumber = middleBlockNumber;
            leftTimestamp = middleTimestamp;
        }

        if (rightBlockNumber - leftBlockNumber <= 1) {
            return leftBlockNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Didn't test it yet.
Will update the code when I have done the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://chaintime.xyz to check the timestamp of a given block number on different chains.